# How to create a Drupal7-View that shows all refering nodes to translation source

Tags: reference, internationalization, drupal-7, translation, drupal-views

I have two content types, one (A: images) refering to the other (B: projects). I also have two languages (en/de). In a view block I show all images (nodes from type A) that refer to a project (nodey from type B):

**Filter criteria:**

- Content: Published (Yes)
- Content: Type (= Project Image)

**Contextual filters:**

- (field_refering_project) Content: Nid

**Relationships:**

- Content: Refering Project

which works great on original language node pages (en). But when I change to translated pages of the projects (de) no images are shown.

I now need to edit the view or create a new view that also shows me the images that refer to the nodes that are the original ones of the translated node that calls the view.
Clear enough? I am not shure...
Thanx!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the problem by adding this code to the page.tpl.php

```
$imagemenuview = views_get_view('projectimagemenu');
echo $imagemenuview->preview('block', array($node->tnid));
```

but still interested in the solution using *Contextual filter: Content: Nid* returning the TNID instead of the NID *When the filter value is NOT available*